# Activex and Php

Tags: php, vb6, wamp, activex, shell-exec

I have designed an Activex.exe in VB6, it uses a Thread Per Object Threading Model, it sends requests to different websites and the returns the data to the user.

The setup is a WAMP Webserver, with a php script that launches the ActiveX with shell_exec, I've only ever used it myself so there has never been an issue with multi requests running at the same time.

I want to be able to allow multi requests to the php script at the same time, having done some testing I find that sending 5 requests works fine, it launches 5 instances of the ActiveX and all run ok, the problem is any more seem to get queued and it only starts the next 1 after each one of the 5 have completed.

So, I was wondering if this is a php resource issue, I have increased the memory limit to 256 meg and monitoring the windows resources there seem to be plenty of free resources mem / cpu ?

Or am I doing things wrong launching the ActiveX with shell_exec ?

One other thing to mention is the VB6 ActiveX is linked after compilation to /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE so it runs in dos, the reason for this is to be able to get a return values back to the php page.

I would appreciate any pointers and suggestions.